# Set 0 for specific value MDX query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, cube

I've been looking around for the answer but I didn't find anything. Sorry if the answer has been given elsewhere.

Here is my problem :

I have a calculated member which is the number of items (of the current member) divided by the total number of items (sumitem).

```
with 
member 
    sumitem
as 
    SUM ([FailureReason].[FailureReason].[All],[Measures].[Items])
member
    Impact
as
    [Measures].[Items]/[Measures].[SumItem]
```

But for a specific member of my dimension **FailureReason**, the result of Impact has to be 0. So I tried to add this :

```
member
    ImpactFinal
as
    iif ([FailureReason].CurrentMember = [FailureReason].[FailureReason].&[127], 
        0, 
        Impact
    )
```

and I select my data like this :

```
select 
    {[Measures].[Items],
     ImpactFinal
     } on columns, 
    [FailureReason].members on rows 
from 
    NoOTAR
```

But instead of getting 0 only for this specific member, every members of this dimension have their ImpactFinal equals to 0. What is strange is if I replace 0 by any other value, the result is good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

`[FailureReason].CurrentMember IS [FailureReason].[FailureReason].&[127]`

instead of

`[FailureReason].CurrentMember = [FailureReason].[FailureReason].&[127]`

and it will work.

**Update**: Several tips:

1. There is also not necessary to use `SUM` function, since you can define only tuple, this will be enough for server: `([FailureReason].[FailureReason].[All],[Measures].[Count])`
2. It's quite reasonable to check `sumitem` measure for dividing by zero in `ImpactFinal` calculation. Because once some filters are applied, this may cause zeroing this measure and errors in reports.
3. If you have an opportunity not only to query, but update cube, `SCOPE ([FailureReason].[FailureReason].&[127],[Measures].[Impact])` with `THIS = 0` is better than additional member because of performance.

Best of luck!

**UPDATE to fix totals:**

If total should be w/o FailureReason 127, you can substitute your measures with:

```
member Impact
as
iif ([FailureReason].[FailureReason].CurrentMember is [FailureReason].[FailureReason].&[127],
        0,
        [Measures].[Items]
    )

member ImpactFinal
as 
iif ([FailureReason].[FailureReason].CurrentMember is [FailureReason].[FailureReason].[All]
    ,[Measures].[Items]-([FailureReason].[FailureReason].&[127],[Measures].[Items])
    ,[Measures].[Impact])/[Measures].[SumItem]
```

But I have another solution, which is more readable:

```
member v2_ImpactUncountableFailure
as
iif ([FailureReason].[FailureReason].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal=0
or 
[FailureReason].[FailureReason].CurrentMember is [FailureReason].[FailureReason].&[127]

,([FailureReason].[FailureReason].&[127],[Measures].[Items])
,null)

member v2_ImpactFinal
as
([Measures].[Items]-[Measures].[v2_ImpactUncountableFailure])
/
([FailureReason].[FailureReason].[All],[Measures].[Items])
```

Use only this two measures instead of set of measures `sumitem`,`Impact`,`ImpactFinal`. First one will show result on failure-127 and total. Second subtracts it from clean unfiltered measure, so in the end we have clean members, zeroed failure-127 and corrected total.

Please let me know if it isn't work, I've tested on my DB and everything is OK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your tips. It works thanks to "IS". However, I thought it would have solved my other problem : my TOTAL result for **Impact** is still 100% (since it's nb of items / nb of items) while I expected it to be (number total of items - number of items of the failure reason 127) / (number total of items). Is it a totaly different problem or is it linked?

Comment: @Gaston G, I've updated an answer according to the new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
with 
member sumitem
as 
    SUM ([FailureReason].[FailureReason].[All],[Measures].[Items])
member LeaveOut
as 
    [FailureReason].[FailureReason].CurrentMember.Properties("Key")   
member Impact
as
    IIf([Measures].[LeaveOut]= "127", 0, [Measures].[Items]/[Measures].[SumItem])
```

Comment: Thnak you for your answer. Unfortunately, the result of **sumitem** gives me the total number of items less the number of items of the members [127]. The value of **sumitem** is never equals to 0, so the value of **Impact** is never 0. Did I miss something ?

Comment: Moreover, I replace [FailureReason].[FailureReason].[All] by [FailureReason].[FailureReason].members because I got a message error "Error infinite recursion detected". Maybe because my dimension has a hierarchy ?

Comment: Hi I thought that the impact had to be 0 for Reason 127.  To solve this add another measure which does not subtract 127 and use that measure as the divisor in the Iif clause

Comment: Ok I have tested this and it works. Instead of Properties("Key") you could use Name

Answer (score 0):

A simple **CASE** statement would solve your problem: Try this

```
With 
Member ImpactFinal As 
CASE 
WHEN [FailureReason].[FailureReason].CurrentMember IS [FailureReason].[FailureReason].&[127] THEN 0
ELSE 
[Measures].[Items]
/
([FailureReason].[FailureReason].[All], [Measures].[Items]) 
END
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Items], ImpactFinal } On Columns
[FailureReason].[FailureReason].Members On Rows
From NoOTAR
```

Comment: I realise the OP says zero but whereever possible in `mdx` you should use `null`, also `CASE` is slower than `IIF`.

Comment: I did not understand about using null. Do you mean filtering empty members?

Comment: @Merin Nakarmi, SSAS engine operates with NULLs faster, than numbers. Detecting sparsity/density causes using block (fast) or cell-by-cell (slow) modes and so on. White paper 'Analysis Services 2008 R2 Performance Guide' describes this things in details.

Comment: Dear @whytheq, thank you very much for enlightening me with the concept of using NULL to enhance performance. Kindly help me understand the idea by implementing it in the above query of mine. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Same request for you as well @AlexPeshik

Comment: Also CASE always performs slower than IIF Mosha ref here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/01/28/performance-of-iif-function-in-mdx.aspx . Maybe since this page was written CASE has been optimized but I think Mosha is implying that CASE will never work in Block mode whereas atleast there is a chance of black mode via IIF